# Explain SQL query in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

The hosting server for a project is using PHPMyAdmin Version: 4.0.5, if I use the SEARCH TAB to perform the search on a single table(while that table is selected) the SQL query built and submitted is shown in a upper window above the result set. but, if I perform a search using SEARCH TAB at the database level (performing a search across multiple tables), there is no SQL code window being displayed and no way to see the SQL that was built/submitted, but it does perform the search and show result sets.

Am I missing a configuration setting or is this by design for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no configuration setting to show the queries in this case. It's probably by design (the resulting queries would take much space) but if you feel you need this, open a feature request at http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests.